# the meaning of the word "wudga"

Tags: meaning

*"Well, wudga marry him for, then?" Mary Jane said.*

This sentence comes from the story Uncly Wiggily in Connecticut by J. D. Salinger. I suppose that "wudga" here means "why do you". Can you tell me how this word is created. On the Internet I have found only "wudga" meaning a hero from old German and Scandinavian legends.

Comment: Could be a contraction of "what did ya" -> "what d'ja" -> "wudja".

Comment: @VictorBazarov Exactly right.

Comment: The "dga" here is pronounced like "ju" in "justice", BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encouraged by StoneyB's reply to my comment,

This is a contraction of "what did you".

> Well, **what did you** marry him for, then? -->
>   Well, **what did ya** marry him for, then? -->
>   Well, **what d'ja** marry him for, then? -->
>   Well, **whadja** marry him for, then? -->
>   Well, **wudga** marry him for, then?